# Code Sign Windows programs with Apple Certificate?

Tags: code-signing, osx-gatekeeper

I'm trying to minimize the cost of code-signing certificates necessary to develop a program for Mac OS X and Windows. As far as I can tell, I can't use a 3rd party certificate to sign my OS X program and have it get past [GateKeeper](https://developer.apple.com/resources/developer-id/), as indicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592638/using-existing-ca-issued-cert-to-sign-os-x-application-and-keep-gatekeeper-happy).

Can I go the other way and use an Apple Developer certificate to sign the Windows version of my program?

Also related:  [Non-Apple Issued Code Signing Certificate: Can it Work with Mac OS 10.8 Gatekeeper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11833481/non-apple-issued-code-signing-certificate-can-it-work-with-mac-os-10-8-gatekeep)

Comment: It's an amazing idea. Have you tried that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Had the same idea some time ago. But I don't think it's possible, because the Apple Developer Certificate is verified (signed) by Apple and I don't think that the Apple Root Certificate is installed on average Windows machines.

Comment: This seems silly.  Surely Apple is a bigger and more trustworthy CA than most.  What CA does Apple use to sign their own Windows apps (e.g. iTunes)?

Comment: I have just checked, and iTunes for Windows is signed with Symantec class 3 signing.

Comment: I should have come here first and saved myself some time and aggravation.

Answer (score 8):

Hi Joe LTNS I check the status of this question every time my Comodo CS certificate comes up for renewal, because hassle/money vs Apple's

Alas, Apple's CA still not in Windows golden list AFAIK. I checked Apple Software Update under Win10 and its cert issuer is Verisign.

OT Not a cert expert here, but if Apple concocted an intermediate cert that both the CA and Apple could vouch/revoke, not a few Windows devs would pony up for Apple's $100 Dev program for that su-weet 5 year non-MAS codesign cert (and probably dabble in App Store/ios development as a bonus)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a detailed article about it: http://luminaryapps.com/blog/code-signing-and-packaging-windows-apps-on-a-mac/ and more generally about code-signing Windows apps on a Mac. I quote:

> Now you need to get a Windows developer certificate. Unfortunately you can't use your Apple certificate (well, actually you can, but it doesn't help because Apple isn't a certificate authority that Windows recognizes). Here is a list of root certificate authorities recognized by Windows.

So this seems to confirm the other answers.