# Does code-signing with the same certificate work on both windows and macOS?

Tags: windows, macos, electron, code-signing

I have built an application using electron and I wanted to sign it using a certificate so that it is not marked as malware on the user's machine. This application needs to run on both windows and macOS.

Do most of these places that sell certificates sell ones that work both on windows and macOS?

Comment: Did find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign a macOS application, you must sign it with your Apple Developer certificate.
You cannot use just any certificate issued by "of these places that sell certificates", but instead you have to sign up for an Apple Developer account and pay your annual fee.

So, the question is, whether you sign  your Windows executables with your Apple certificate (or rather: whether the average Windows machine will accept such a signature).

As has been answered for [Code Sign Windows programs with Apple Certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468783), the answer is: no.
Even Windows software produced by Apple themselves (e.g. `iTunes`) does not use the Apple keychain.